car movement (side scroller)
i am using game maker studio 2
i want to make simple car movement but the joints aren't working well, i already tried different joint functions, i don't know what function to use, here's my code :

physics_joint_distance_create(id,car_body, x, y, obj_car_body.x , obj_car_body.y,0)

physics_joint_distance_create(id,car_body, x, y, obj_car_body.x - 70, obj_car_body.y,0) ```


Can you specify "the joints aren't working"?

Is there more to your example than you've shown? physics_joint_distance_create constrains the distance between two points on two instances must be constant. It's for joining things together, it doesn't apply any movement by itself. If you're looking for movement functions, I would start with the Movement And Collisions section of the online manual.

Possible duplicate of this Game Maker question: Simple 2d Movement (Non platformer).

@Steven
i meant the joint aren't staying still, they're moving which is causing the wheels to move in unwanted directions, i tried using other types of joints but none seem to work for me

@Pikalek
i dont have problem with the moving itself, as i applied the necessary movement functionality (torque), the problem is that the joints aren't staying in place.

It seems like there's are some essential descriptive & technical details missing from your question. Please edit to provide a minimal, reproducible example and a more complete description of your problem.
